# Remove extra geometry from objects

Tags: modeling, topology, geometry

Is there a tool or an easier way to remove unneeded geometry from objects? Mostly when using a "Displace" modifier, on many places there are flat surfaces where there is extra geometry on the mesh, that you would like them to be removed. At first I thought of the "Decimate" modifier, but is there a way to do it more evenly. By preserving the edge/face flow and such. Is there some feature for something like that in Blender?

- From this

[image]

- To this

[image]

- Or to this (if I want the geometry to be to the very limits and worrying only about the shape)

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Manual with good topology

To get the topology in your second image. Select the loops you want to delete with <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd>, or in *Wireframe* mode use border select (<kbd>B</kbd>). Then press <kbd>Delete</kbd> and choose *Edge Loops*.

## Manual with N-gons

To delete all edges and vertices on a face and just be left with a large N-gon. Select all the faces on a plane (example everything on the top); then press <kbd>Delete</kbd> and choose *Limited Dissolve*.

## Modifiers

If you are less picky about topology, and want a more automatic solution Then use a *Decimate* modifier. For examples like your's set the *Decimate* modifier to *Planar*, then adjust the angle limit to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, but that's why I mentioned the "Displace" modifier. You just end up with too much of a geometry. Is there a more automated approach for something like this and maybe doing it evenly, by keeping the edge/face flow and such?

Comment: Another manual technique I like to use is just "Dissolve" (Vertices, Edges, or Faces).  It's on the x menu.  But it's much more manual than the techniques listed in the answer.

Comment: wow, Limited Dissolve did the trick. I love Blender! As well as people sharing their wisdom. Thanks!

Comment: Where is a Decimate modifier?

Answer (score 14):

I would use *limited dissolve* as [mentioned by David](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15583/599), but in case you want to do this non-destructively, then you can use the [Decimate modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Decimate) in Planar mode.

[image]

Comment: come on, that was crazy. I had already edited my answer with the modifier and was adding the headings when you answered it. :)

Comment: @David lol, that's what happened to me in that licensing question. :P

Comment: that happens a lot here.  It's amusing since this could only happen a lot if answers were being provided right away to questions asked.  This is easily the most well maintained Q&A sites I've encountered.  Good work all y'all.

Comment: "Limited dissolve" was what I was looking for after all