# CAD file into blender, round shapes not round

Tags: modeling

A client of mine send me a .obj file (which was exported out of a CAD file). But on importing into Blender, I noticed the round shapes aren't like they are supposed to, see image attached. Is there any way to fix this, besides fixing all the vertices manual?
[image]

Comment: Blender only reads whatever information is already in the file, if shapes aren't round enough it is because they were not exported round enough. With topology like that there's is little you can do to get decent results other than manually fix.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, I was afraid so, thanks Duarte!

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Would there be any way to get a better import from CAD to Blender though? I only got the .obj conversion from my client, but maybe I could ask them for a different conversion.

Comment: Related: [Importing models from AutoCAD to Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/141181/78972)

Comment: File format is not the issue here, obj may be fine. You can get better results regardless, you just need better export setting. That is neither on topic here, nor something we can help you with however, since we don't even know what CAD application it came from. That is something your client should be able to provide given he has access to the CAD original

Comment: Do you have any experience on what settings would work best here? @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: Most CAD-suites should have an options panel in the export tool, where you can specify face size and angle threshold for mesh export. It's a tradeoff between file size and detail, you might want to experiment a bit with the values to find the best setting for your needs.


Alternatively, you could look into the stepper-tool (https://gumroad.com/l/stepper), which can convert CAD formats into blender. It's not free, though.

Comment: Thanks @haarigertroll. I indeed had my client re-export with with a lot more detail (a 500mb file compared to 36mb what it was). Of course it runs less smooth but the curves are flawless now. Problem solved, thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score -2):

If the mesh hasn't been tampered with, I'm guessing this is a situation caused by incorrect smoothing information. A normals related issue.

Make sure when you export, you export the smoothing information correctly. After importing it into blender you have 'shade smooth' set, and then play with auto-smooth angle.