# How do I reduce mesh complexity?

Tags: mesh

I'm still new to blender and started modelling a star ship. its basic form is a sphere with a vertically cut torus around its equator.

On that torus it has 24 plasma engine exhausts facing north, 24 on the underside of the torus facing south.

Around its sphere it has about 120 hangars and more than a 100 weapon turrets. I had to spend a lot of time coming as far as the Sphere with the engine outlets and added 24 turrets, which took forever.

Having tried a lot of versions of where and torus, starting with 64 segments and 24 rings, I had to use  1024 segments at last and subdivision multiplier to finally come up with a sphere that really looked like the ship. But now I don't know how to reduce the complexity of the mesh - sphere and torus are already more than 38 million vertices and +37 mio. faces.

Every turret adds another 1.5 mio. I´m working on an older iMac from 2011, 16 GB 1333 MHz DDR3 and a 2,7 GHz Intel Core i5. Working comes more or less to a standstill and every now and then the mac completely crashes.

I am afraid all that work so far was for nothing, as I have neither completed the ship nor started on creating a scene and animation.

Help would be very welcomed!

Comment: pleas eddit your question and add screnshots for better understanding of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to blender, then start with healthier habits before they turn into vices...

One common error new users make is subdividing too early and creating unnecessary dense topology.

Not only does it make editing way more complicated than what it should be, but will push your computer to its limits very quickly, then you will run out of resources for rigging, animating, doing simulations, particles, volumetrics and, finally, for rendering. Keep it real... Computing power is limited, use it wisely.

Start with simple shapes and work with the absolute minimum number of vertices that give you the shape you are after.

Read: [common pitfalls of beginning modellers](https://www.lifewire.com/common-pitfalls-of-beginning-modelers-2052)

Given that you've already put yourself on a bind... use (and apply) the decimate modifier, reduce unnecessary geometry with dissolve edges and faces, and try to keep the number of vertices in check.

For elements that are repeated, model only one and use instances, arrays, dupliverts, duplifaces and dupliframes, those require less resources (read: [What techniques have been used to repeat geometry or other detail to the infinite horizon?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9206/what-techniques-have-been-used-to-repeat-geometry-or-other-detail-to-the-infinit))

Softer and rounder meshes can be accomplished with smooth shading, multires, smooth and subsurf modifiers. And speaking of subsurf modifiers, avoid using large values. Hardly ever you should need more than a value of 3. Read: [Blender render crash when using subsurf modifiers.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/blender-render-crash-when-using-subsurf-modifiers/28283#28283).

If your quest for detail is part of an obsessive compulsive need to detail things, then create a dense mesh, a normal map and use that map to fake the detail on lower poly meshes.

3d is always a fine balance between artistic goals and the realities of the available computing power.

Sorry if I rain on your parade, but you won't be able to create the prequel to the sequel to the reboot of your favorite sci-fi blockbuster movie in 8K on your personal computer... But that doesn't mean that you can't do amazing work in blender and learn and have lots of fun in the meantime! If you maximize and use your resources in a smart way and keep your expectations on a realistic level, your experience will be more enjoyable.

Three pieces of unrequested advice:

1- Optimize.

2- Don't complicate what shouldn't be complex (optimize)

3- Use detail only in the places where there is no alternative way to cheat (optimize)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your mesh is composed of many copys of the same things.
considder using [linked duplicats](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/duplication.html) so your changes on the original apply to all of them.

Then for the thing you are duplicating carefully [remove unnessesary topology](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15581/remove-extra-geometry-from-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Hi j.Doe! I already used the decimate modifier on the ship and the turrets. Set them to.2 and sub to 2. But I still got 8.4 mio vertices and - strange enough - 15.2 mio  faces after adding 20 of the gun turrets. I already checked the turrets completely for hidden duplicates - there shouldn't be any left. I don't know how to proceed with the mothership. And the mac is still super slow.